# Is Swift REALLY more accurate in terms of timing than Objective C

Tags: objective-c, swift

I'm from the Windows world, and C# is less accurate in terms of timing than C or C++. I did a metronome program in C#, and needed to use C for the accurate timing of the metronome.

I saw this:[Swift vs Objective-C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28452862/swift-vs-objective-c-app-performance) and it does lead me to believe that Swift is more accurate in terms of timing that Objective C, but I wanted to make sure that was accurate.

Your answers will be appreciated!

Comment: Performance is not the same as accuracy. Are you talking about the accuracy of NSTimer for example?

Comment: Yes, I'm wondering about the accuracy of NSTimer. That's an extremely good timer.

Comment: You may be disheartened to learn that NSTimer is an Objective-C class. Bridging it over the Swift can only increase the overhead and the best you can hope for is a no-delay compared to ObjC. [Apple said](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSTimer_Class/index.html) NSTimer resolution is limited to 50 - 100 ms.

Comment: I seem to recall that there is another timer that is more accurate? Not sure what it's name is, I thought it was NSTimer.

Comment: Read this: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/technotes/tn2169/_index.html